# v-rep strange number format

Tags: numbers, scientific-notation

I'm trying to use v-rep and following a simple tutorial. But the numbers in all windows follows sci-notation format (see the picture). Can any  one tell me there to change this?

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I sent a mail to Coppelia Robotics and they basically said that there is no way to switch to a regular notation and they used sci notation in the name of precision. So we have to live with it.